# Magento 2.3 Multi source inventory module - Does it work for Bundled products?

Tags: bundled-product, inventory, magento2.3

Magento 2.3 Multi source inventory module - Does it work for Bundled products?

MSI roadmap says it is in Milestone 3. So if I implement the MSI Module as of today into a catalogue of simple and bundled products, will it not allow the bundled products to work alongside? Seem to be having trouble getting it shipped.
https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/wiki/MSI-Roadmap#mls3

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.3.0 + MSI supports bundle products in Single Stock Mode (on Default Source and Default Stock). In this setup Magento reuses legacy CatalogInventory Stock Status index where Bundle products supported. That's why merchants who use Bundle products on a single stock are not affected.

You can read more about Supported Product types here:
https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/inventory-about-product-types.html

Currently, there is no possibility to assign Bundle Products to custom sources, as a new Inventory indexation mechanism (which builds indexes per each Stock) does not support indexation of Bundle Products yet. This functionality is part of Milestone 3 MSI backlog which you mentioned above.